# python xml parsing; multiple xml files

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have multiple xml files with similar elements. How to extract the child elements from multiple files? I wrote a sample code which extracts the required elements from a single file but I need to extract from multiple xml files.the major problem here is it should print the required feilds only if admin-server-name equals to name

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.dom.minidom
cmd = "find . / -name config.xml 2>/dev/null |grep -w config/config.xml"
p = commands.getoutput(cmd)
count=0;
admnprt=[]
lstnaddr=[]
dmnver=[]
admnsrvnme=[]
serverName=[]
word=p.rstrip().split('\n')
print word
print "no of domains are %s" %len(word)
for line in word :
        count =count +1
        DomTree =xml.dom.minidom.parse(line)
    domain=DomTree.documentElement
        admnprt=domain.getElementsByTagName("administration-port")
    lstnaddr=domain.getElementsByTagName("listen-address")
    admnsrvnme=domain.getElementsByTagName("admin-server-name")
    dmnver=domain.getElementsByTagName("domain-version")
    serverName = document.getElementsByTagName("name")
    if(serverName == "admnsrvnme"):
        for i in admnprt:
            print "administration-port for %s domain is " % count + " " + "%s" %i.childNodes[0].data
        for j in lstnaddr:
            print "listen-address for %s domain is " % count + " " + "%s" %j.childNodes[0].data


    for a in admnsrvnme:
        print "admin-server-name for %s domain is " % count + " " + "%s" %a.childNodes[0].data
    for b in dmnver:
        print "domain-version for %s domain is " % count + " " + "%s" %b.childNodes[0].data
```

Comment: if you have new code than edit your question (add new code below your old code with title "@edit:"). Than You can write in comments below my answer that you add new information to your question. Don't edit my answer. If I find new solution to your problem I put it in my answer.

Comment: sorry furas!please do excuse me... am very new to python please help me with the edited code

Comment: Can you add: output you get, output you expect, and some config.xml files ? Or you can send it on mail: bartlomiej.burek@gmail.com

Comment: thanku furas !!! i have mailed you the document please do check in your inbox

Answer (score 0):

Put your code to function and call it for all files.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

def parse_file(filename):
    DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse(filename)
    domain=DOMTree.documentElement
    name=domain.getElementsByTagName("domain-version")[0]
    print" %s" % name.childNodes[0].data
    adminservername=domain.getElementsByTagName("admin-server-name")[0]
    print " %s" % adminservername.childNodes[0].data
    listenaddress=domain.getElementsByTagName("listen-address")[0]
    print " %s" % listenaddress.childNodes[0].data
    administrationport=domain.getElementsByTagName("administration-port")[0]
    print " %s" % administrationport.childNodes[0].data

for argument in sys.argv[1:] :
    parse_file(argument)
```

Now you can run script with many filenames

`yourscript.py filename1 filename2`

Comment: thank you furas !! please help me with the above formatted way.the config.xml file contains <admin-server-name> and many <servers> the code should be able to print the <listen-address> and <administration-port> only if <name> in <server> equals to <admin-server-name> am unable to form the correct condition for this